# Material-UI Migration Helper: codemod-script?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, migration, material-ui, jscodeshift

I'm updating from Material-UI 0.x to 1.0.

The docs for [migration-helper](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-codemod) say to run:

```
 jscodeshift -t <codemod-script> <path>.
```

I've never used jscodeshift before, and I've never seen the notation  before, so I would like to get some advice on how to use this. :) Googling `jscodeshift codemod-script` brings up nothing relevant.

What does `codemod-script` need to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a bit to figure this out. After you've installed jscodeshift and the material-ui codemods, the command should be formatted as follows:

`jscodeshift -t <the file path of the specific code mod file> <the location of the files you want to process>`

`jscodeshift -t ./node_modules/@material-ui/codemod/lib/v1.0.0/svg-icon-imports.js ./src/`

I also use the extension jsx for my files so I had to add the --extensions flag:

`jscodeshift -t ./node_modules/@material-ui/codemod/lib/v1.0.0/svg-icon-imports.js ./src/ --extensions jsx`

Comment: Very good. Do I run it one time for every m-ui file I import, e.g `material-ui/List`, `material-ui/Avatar`, etc.?

Comment: All at once from what I can tell, but I just got it running myself, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The example command in your post, `jscodeshift -t ./node_modules/@material-ui/codemod/lib/v1.0.0/svg-icon-imports.js ./src/ --extensions jsx`, seems to just be for one m-ui file, `svg-icon-imports.js ./`.  That's why I had the impression I would run it one time for every m-ui file. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: Oh yes, I could only get it to run one code-mod at a time. Honestly, I found them rather buggy and not a whole lot of help. I ran them, but I'm still doing 90% of the work by hand.